# Delete file if it is owned by specific user

Tags: linux, perl

There is a file that is sometimes not owned by root

I want my perl script in linux to basically check if a file is owned by root if it is delete it.

Currently what I have `unlink("$File_Path/File_Name");`

but this just deletes the file I want it to check if it's owned by root first then delete otherwise ignore.

can you please guide me how I can achieve this I am out of ideas?

Comment: `stat -c %u`? to get the UID of the owner? If it is `0`, then it's owned by root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) shows that the fifth element in the returned list is "*numeric user ID of file's owner*".  The superuser account on *nix *must* have uid of `0`, so

```
if ( (stat $fqn)[4] == 0 ) {
    unlink $fqn or die "Error with unlink($fqn): $!";
}
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that if `use File::stat;` is included, you can then use more readable symbolic names for the stat elements instead of numeric array indices, e.g. `(stat $fqn)->uid` in place of `(stat $fqn)[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this to a bunch of files in a folder somewhere, you might be better off by just one of these:

```
find /folder/somewhere/ -type f -user root -exec rm {} \;
find /folder/somewhere/ -type f -user root -exec rm -i {} \;   #interactive y/n each file
find /folder/somewhere/ -type f -user root -print0 | xargs -r0 rm
```

You might also need `sudo` in front of `find`. Careful though, this is a kind of command that can do a lot of harm...